# Playing HTML video while taking a screenshot (drawHierarchy)

Tags: html, ios, ipad, video, swift3

I'm having issues with **thumbnailWebView.drawHierarchy(in:,afterScreenUpdates:)** method and loading HTML code with a local video in it.

The issue comes when I capture the webview to get a tumbnail and then I click the video on the webview, the video start running (because the sound works) but the image keeps black. Also if I click the full screen option the video shows right.

The code is simple. Image capture:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.thumbnailWebView.bounds.size, true, UIScreen.main.scale)
thumbnailWebView.drawHierarchy(in: thumbnailWebView.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
let screenShot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

Init WKWebView:

```
let conf = WKWebViewConfiguration()
self.thumbnailWebView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 768, height: 1024), configuration: conf)
thumbnailGeneratorView.addSubview(self.thumbnailWebView)
thumbnailControl = ThumbnailControl()
thumbnailControl.delegate = self
thumbnailWebView.uiDelegate = thumbnailControl
thumbnailWebView.navigationDelegate = thumbnailControl
```

Loading the HTML:

```
self.thumbnailWebView.loadFileURL(contentURL!, allowingReadAccessTo: contentURL!.deletingLastPathComponent())
```

If I comment the drawHierarchy line, the video shows right.

I have also tried to use **view.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)** instead drawHierarchy but the screenshot obtained is white.